# Why name is not displayed using $el.html() in backbonejs

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have folowing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<title>Title</title>
```

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
   var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    className : 'myClass'
});  

var aView = new myView();
console.log(aView.el);

var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
      name: 'User1',
      age: 27,
      occupation: 'SE'
  }
});

var anotherView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    initialize : function(){
        console.log("called View");
        this.render();
    },
    render : function (){
        console.log("model : " + this.model.get('name'));
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('name'));

    }
});

var person = new Person();
var fstView = new anotherView({model:person});
console.log(fstView.el);
```

here, this.$el.html(this.model.get('name')); is not displaying anything on browser.

Answer (score 1):

In `anotherView` you have specified `tagName` as `li`. This creates a `li` element but does not add it to DOM and hence nothing is displayed in the browser. So, if you are creating view's `el` from `tagName`, `className` or `id` then you need to make sure you add it to DOM.

Add the last line below to you code.

```
var person = new Person();
var fstView = new anotherView({model:person});
console.log(fstView.el);
$('body').html(fstView.el);
```

Have a look at [view.el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) and [what is el](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#what-is-el).

NOTE: Make sure you have a `ul` and then add corresponding `li's` to it.